# Ubuntu 12.04 does not boot after installation appears to succeed

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot

After successfully installing ubuntu 12.04 on a Sony VAIO SVE14115FN (E series) it's not booting up. Just displaying an error: "Operating System Not Loaded" 
Please help me in this.

Comment: Were there any errors during the installation? What happens exactly after you press the power button?

Comment: no there were not any error during the installation. I installed ubuntu 12.04 through CD then it showed ubuntu is installed successfully then I restarted my system but it was not showing any boot screen.

Answer (score 1):

**If you installed Ubuntu by itself** (so it's the only OS on the PC), or ***alongside* another OS** by booting from a live CD/DVD or USB flash drive, and you get an "Operating System Not Loaded" error when you try to boot up, reinstall Ubuntu's GRUB2 boot loader to the Master Boot Record. (This is sometimes caused by it not being correctly installed by Ubuntu's installer.) You can use any of the methods on these pages:

- [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)
  (This applies even though your problem was not caused by a recent installation of Windows.)
- [GRUB2/Installing, Reinstalling GRUB 2, Fixing a Broken System](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System)

If you **installed Ubuntu inside Windows with Wubi**, then you should not use those techniques--in that case, the problem is most likely that the Windows boot loader is not booting Ubuntu. In that case, you'll have to let us know you used Wubi, and provide more information (any other errors? does the error occur before or after you select Ubuntu in the boot menu? does Windows still boot?).

I'm guessing you installed Ubuntu as a standalone system (not in Wubi) since you said you installed it "through CD." But you can also install Wubi by running `wubi.exe` on an Ubuntu desktop CD, so I don't know this for sure.